# Match position alignment of scrolling backgrounds horizontally across separate divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, display

(Tl;dr in italics, below)

My page so far consists of a mix of five independent- and multi-classed divs (read: "panels") (`.panel {}`) that I've formatted with CSS using `display: table-cell`.  They are contained within a surrounding wrapper (`.wrapper {}`) that is likewise formatted with `display: table`.

For the purposes of this question, if we were to label them as they appear within the currently-loading page from left to right as Panels 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, then

Panel 3 (`.main {}`) is set at `width: 850px`,

Panels 2 & 4 (`.conveyor {}`) are set at `width: 20px`,

and

Panels 1 & 5 (`#leftBG {}` and `#rightBG {}`, repsectively) are set at `width: 100%`.

The result is five divs with class "panel" spaced evenly across the page, set at `height: 100%`, with widths as mentioned above.

I have a button that, when clicked, uses the jQuery UI `.addClass()` effect to widen the 2nd and 4th panels, each by 180 pixels (as in this case, from 20px [`.conveyor {}`] to 200px [`.showConveyor`] ) .

**The problem:** I have a small background I want to be able to scroll, to repeat to span the entire page, to be visible in divs 1, 3, and 5, and to look like a standard `body { background-image: background.jpg; repeat: repeat; background-attachment: scroll; }` repeating background, *but which should move in accordance with the expansion of Panels 2 & 4, such that it will appear to be pushed by Panel 2 180 pixels to the left within Panel 1, and by Panel 4 180 pixels to the right within Panel 5.*

I currently have it set so that the backgrounds in either panel (of 1 & 5) move in the direction they're supposed to by the correct number of pixels, but the split-background starting positions do not match what a standard repeating background would look like, if we imagine that divs 1, 3, and 5 are transparent divs in front of a repeating `body {}` background image that uses the same `background.jpg` called for by both `#leftBG {}` and `#rightBG {}`.

If someone could give me an idea of how I can set the starting background positions of divs 1, 3, and 5, such that they would, combined, match what a standard `body` background looks like, but so that Panels 2 & 4 still widen and move the backgrounds of Panels 1 & 5 as described when the button is clicked, I would be much obliged.

jQuery (UI):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $( "button" ).click( function() {
        $( ".conveyor" ).addClass( "showConveyor" , 400 ) ;
    } ) ;
} ) ;
```

CSS

```
html {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

div {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    position: relative;
}

div.wrapper {
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

div.panel {
    display:table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}

div.push { // had something here; lost it
}

#leftBG {
    background: url("background.jpg");
    background-size: 400px;
    background-attachment: local;
    background-position: right top;
}

#rightBG {
    background: url("background.jpg");
    background-size: 400px;
    background-attachment: local;
    background-position: left top;
}

div.spacer {
    width: 20px;
    background: gray;
}

div.conveyor {
    width: 20px;
    background: red;
}

div.showConveyor {
    width: 200px;
}

div.main {
    width: 850px;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="panel push" id="leftBG"></div>
        <div class="panel conveyor"></div>
        <div class="panel main">
            <button>Howdy</button>
        </div>
        <div class="panel conveyor"></div>
        <div class="panel push" id="rightBG"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: @madalinivascu Updated

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to accomplish here. What should happen when the button is clicked? What is not working? Testing here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/bqjv30tz/

Comment: @Twisty

You know how a repeating background in a standard `body{}` element looks, right?

The button is supposed to make the page behave in such a way as to look like the button splits such a background into three pieces: the center piece (Panel 3) should stay where it is, the leftmost piece (Panel 1) should move to the left x number of pixels, and the rightmost piece (Panel 5) should move to the right x number of pixels.

Comment: @StephenHanson do you want to boundaries to move and the background to remain the same or to have it appear to open more, where the background moves?

Comment: @StephenHanson will there be content in the "panels"? If not would a `div` that changes it's shape and margins be useful?

Comment: @Twisty Panels 2, 3, and 4 will all have content.  The content in 2 and 4 is overflown (hidden) until the panels open.

The background should literally look like it's on a piece of paper, cut into three strips, with the first and last strips moved to the side to reveal content in panels 2 and 4.